# How do i print the memory address of void**?

Tags: c

I am trying to print the void* memory address inside void**, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    void** MyArray = malloc(500 * sizeof(void*));
    printf("Last pointer: %p\n", *MyArray[499]);
    free(MyArray);
    return 0;

}
```

But when i try to compile I get a warning and an error:

> 1. Line: 6   Col: 31 in D:\C\test.c  [Warning] dereferencing 'void *' pointer
> 2. Line: 6 Col: 2 in D:\C\test.c [Error] invalid use of void expression

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `*MyArray[499]` should be `MyArray[499]`.

Comment: MyArray is initialized, but its members are not.  So you'll be printing an uninitialized variable, that is, garbage.  Quite aside from the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate memory to hold an array to hold a bunch of void pointers.  This array doesn't contain any pointers yet.  If you want the address of the last position in the array, do this:

```
int main(){
    void** MyArray = malloc(500 * sizeof(void*));
    printf("Last pointer is located at: %p\n", (void *)&(MyArray[499]));
    free(MyArray);
    return 0;

}
```